# Formula for degree of field extensions

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

Let $E$ and $K$ be extensions over some base field $F$. Let $m=[E:E\cap K]$ and $n =[K:E\cap K]$. Is $[KE:K\cap E] = mn$?

It seems to good to be true. We know that $[KE:K\cap E]\leq mn$ by counting dimension, and equality holds if $m$ and $n$ are coprime. Also, if $E/{E\cap K}$ and $K/{E\cap K}$ are Galois equality also holds. So any counterexample to this must be constructed quite carefully. I haven't been able to so far. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A counterexample is given in Example $2.4.$ in Conrad's [notes](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&ved=0ahUKEwjc07TaidLXAhUEfhoKHd0DAHoQFghSMAU&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.uconn.edu%2F~kconrad%2Fblurbs%2Fgaloistheory%2Fgaloiscorrthms.pdf&usg=AOvVaw37ryiEvHzAqXwAS6vsLuTz), together with a diagram of field extensions:

If $F=\mathbb{Q}$, $E=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$, and $K=\mathbb{Q}(\omega \sqrt[3]{2})$, then
$$
[KE:K\cap E]=6,
$$
but
$$
[K:K\cap E]\cdot [E:K\cap E]=9.
$$
We have $K\cap E=F=\mathbb{Q}$. K. Conrad gives a second counterexample, namely Example $2.5$.